# How to use the "__str__" method?

Tags: python

I'm diving into some Object Oriented Programming. Unfortunately, I can't even get up to the first step: Converting classes to strings using `__str__`.

Here's my code:

```
class Time:

    def __init__(self, hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0):
        self.hours = hours
        self.minutes = minutes
        self.seconds = seconds

    def __str__(self):
        return "basdfadsg"



time1 = Time

time1.hours = 3
time1.minutes = 23
time1.seconds = 13

print(time1)
```

Whenever I try:

```
print(time1)
```

it returns:

```
<class '__main__.Time'>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need an *instance* of `Time`.  e.g. `time1 = Time()`  (Notice the parenthesis).

As it is, you are modifying the *class*, not an *instance* of the class -- And `__str__` only tells python how to create strings from instances of the class, not the classes themselves...

Comment: That was awfully quick.

Comment: @MarkRansom -- Right place at the right time I suppose.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to add a `__str__` method to the class object itself? Not that it would be useful, I'm just curious.

Comment: @MarkRansom -- Yeah, I was actually wondering the same thing ...

Comment: Oh my gosh sir, thank you so much. I feel so lucky to be part of this community. Thanks for the speed as well. I'll accept your answer in 2 minutes, haha.

Answer (score 2):

IF you really are trying to have a `__str__` or `__repr__` for a class vs an instance of the class, you need to use metaclasses this way:

```
>>> class Test(type):
...    def __repr__(self):
...       return 'Test is my name'
... 
>>> class MT(object):
...    __metaclass__=Test
... 
>>> print MT
Test is my name
```

But, as others have said, it is more likely that you are not referring to an instance of Time by calling `__init__`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
time1 = Time
```

You are not creating an INSTANCE of class Time and passing that to time1, but instead are passing the TYPE of that class to time1.

To have this code work as you want, simply call the object constructor:

```
time1 = Time()
```

You may be thinking "Why would anyone ever need a variable to hold a TYPE instead of an INSTANCE?" Well, in Python, class definitions (and almost everything else) are first class objects that can be modified at runtime allowing members and member functions to be dynamically added/removed from the class definition. Have fun *pythoning*, it's truly a blast.

Comment: Thank you, equally helpful!

Answer (score 0):

A 2023 answer.  Try using `__repr__` instead of `__str__`.  According to this answer, I am not attempting to print out an instance but a type.  However, in my code I am creating instances and appending to a list and when I want to print out that list `__repr__` is being invoked, should it be present.

Comment: This is incorrect - as said in the other answers, they just need to initialise the class.